# Access UISegmentedControl in table view cell from view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a cell with a UISegmentedControl. This control is connected to the table view cell, and not my view controller. But I need to know which index is selected to populate the table view with correct array.

How do I access the segmented controller in the table view cell from the view controller?

Comment: Create a protocol, make view controller to act as delegate of the cell. When item of segment control is touched, call the delegate method.

Comment: Thanks, do you have an example for me? I've can't quite understand how to implement this protocol

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways by which you can go about this, one way would be to use a protocol, define a protocol with a method such as `didSelectCellSegmentedControl(segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl, selectedSegmentIndex index: Int)`. Then make your viewcontroller the delegate of the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method`, conform to the `didSelectCellSegmentedControl` protocol and handle the selection there.

Comment: Hmm, ok. I've never used protocols before, and not sure where to start. Do you have any examples or links for me to check out?

Comment: You can start by understanding how protocols work here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html. Then head over to this quick example http://useyourloaf.com/blog/quick-guide-to-swift-delegates/